# error: The dependency graph could not be satisfied Vapor Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, vapor

When I run in terminal `vapor xcode` to fetch the packages I get error `The dependency graph could not be satisfied (https://github.com/vapor/crypto.git)`
What is it caused by and how can I fix it. Package.swift file content is

```
 import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "StripePayment",
dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1),
   .Package(url:"https://github.com/siemensikkema/vapor-jwt.git", majorVersion: 0)



],
exclude: [
    "Config",
    "Database",
    "Localization",
    "Public",
    "Resources",
    "Tests",
]
)
```

Comment: Try changing your Vapor version to 1.5: `.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 5),`

Comment: @CalebKleveter It works, the framework for JWT has been renamed though

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the name of your JWT package and the version of the Vapor package:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "StripePayment",
dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 5),
    .Package(url:"https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", majorVersion: 0)



],
exclude: [
    "Config",
    "Database",
    "Localization",
    "Public",
    "Resources",
    "Tests",
]
)
```